# How to define the password protection scheme (e.g. hash function) used by ldappasswd?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am using OpenLDAP 2.6. When I set an object's password via

```
ldappasswd -x -D <dn of root user> -W -S <dn of object whose pwd shall be set>
```

then some hash of the password end up in the attribute `userPassword`.

What hash function does `ldappasswd` use? How do I configure the hash function? From the look of it, I assume it defaults to a SHA1 which isn't secure anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What hash function does ldappasswd use?

Technically none – it just invokes the 'Change Password' LDAP Extended Operation which causes the LDAP **server** to use some hash function it finds appropriate (and to store the hash in wherever it finds appropriate – not necessarily in userPassword).

So the hash used by the 'Change Password' exop is configured server-side. For OpenLDAP, that's the `olcPasswordHash` parameter which defaults to "SSHA" (salted and iterated SHA-1), similar to `$1$` hashes. If you want something stronger, you can choose either `{CRYPT}` to use whatever hash algorithms the system's crypt() function provides (i.e. the same as with /etc/shadow – possibly bcrypt or yescrypt if the OS uses libxcrypt, otherwise the same sort of salted SHA), *or* `{ARGON2}` if you have the additional slapd-argon2 module installed (it's part of OpenLDAP but in the "contrib" tree).

| slapd.conf | cn=config |
| --- | --- |
| Default (iterated/salted SHA-1): `password-hash {SSHA}` | Default: `olcPasswordHash: {SSHA}` |
| System crypt() using yescrypt, if libxcrypt is in use: `password-hash {CRYPT}` `password-crypt-salt-format $y$%.16s` (not tested but I think that should work) | System crypt() using yescrypt: `olcPasswordHash: {CRYPT}` `olcPasswordCryptSaltFormat: $y$.16s` |
| Argon2 if the slapd module is available: `moduleload argon2` `password-hash {ARGON2}` | Argon2 if the slapd module is available: `olcModuleLoad: argon2` `olcPasswordHash: {ARGON2}` |